# How get the long-run proportion of times the vector is still $(1, 1,\dots, 1)$ which flips uniformly random?

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> Suppose that there exists a $n-$dimensional vector $(1, 1,\dots, 1)$ which are all $1$. For this vector doing the following: at each step, choose one of $i$-th coordinate uniformly at random and flipped, i.e. turns $1$ into $0$ and vice-versa. Clearly, this is a Markov chain.
>
> What is the long-run proportion of times the vector is still $(1, 1,\dots, 1)$?

It is easy to show that this MC is irreducible. I try to assume that the $X_n$ is the number of $1$ in the vector after $n$ flips. So how to get
$$\pi_n =\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^kP_{nn}^m?$$
where $P_{nn}^m=\mathbb{P}(X_m=n\mid X_0=n)$.

Is there any more direct method to get the result $1/2^n$? I feel like this chain similar to the expectation of a simple randon walk return to its starting point.

Comment: all vectors are identical in the long run

Comment: @dEmigOd Could you give some details? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that for any given sequence of flips, we land back on our original vector if and only if each coordinate is flipped an even number of times (possibly $0$).
It follows that after an odd number of flips, we can never land back on the original vector.
We will hence consider only sequences where $L=2k$ is even.

For any length $L=2k$, the total number of sequences of flips is $n^{2k}$.
Let's count the number of sequences of flips which satisfy the parity requirement.

Let $2v_i$ be the number of flips at position $i$.
We must have

$$\sum_{i=1}^nv_i = k \tag{$1$}$$

where $0\leq v_i \leq k$ are integers.
Now, for each solution to $(1)$, we can order the flips in

$$\binom{2k}{2v_1,2v_2,\dots,2v_n}$$

distinct ways.
This would give the total number of sequences as

$$\sum_{v_1+v_2+\dots+v_n = k} \binom{2k}{2v_1,2v_2,\dots,2v_n} \tag{2}.$$

[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248141/sum-of-multinomial-coefficients-even-distribution) shows that $(2)$ can be rewritten as

$$\frac1{2^n }\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}m{(n-2m)}^{2k}\tag{3},$$

and hence the probability that after a sequence of $2k$ flips we are back to the original vector is

$$p_{2k} = \frac{\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}m{(n-2m)}^{2k}}{2^n n^{2k}}.$$

The quantity you seek can be explicitly written as $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac1{2k} \sum_{j=1}^k p_{2j}$.
I haven't really found a way to show that it reduces to $1/2^n$ yet.

EDIT:
Rewrite

$$p_{2k} = \frac1{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}m{\left(1-\frac{2m}n\right)}^{2k},$$

and reorder the summations in the limit expression to obtain

$$\frac1{2k\cdot2^n}\left(\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}m \sum_{j=1}^k {\left(1-\frac{2m}n\right)}^{2j}\right). \tag{4}$$

Separately sum the indices $m=0$ and $m=n$ to obtain

$$\frac1{2k\cdot2^n}\left(2k+\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}m \sum_{j=1}^k {\left(1-\frac{2m}n\right)}^{2j}\right)
\\=
\frac1{2^n} + \underbrace{\frac1{2k\cdot2^n}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}m \sum_{j=1}^k {\left(1-\frac{2m}n\right)}^{2j}\right)}_{\alpha}.$$

We show that as $k\to\infty$, $\alpha$ approaches $0$.

Notice that for $1\leqslant m \leqslant n-1$, we have ${\left(1-\frac{2m}n\right)}^{2j} \leqslant {\left(1-\frac2n\right)}^{2j}$.
Let $t = {\left(1-\frac2n\right)}^2$ and notice that $|t|<1$ and that $t$ depends only on $n$.
Write

\begin{align}
0\leqslant
\alpha
&\leqslant
\frac1{2k\cdot 2^n}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}m \sum_{j=1}^k t^j
\\&=
\frac1{2k\cdot 2^n}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}m \frac{t(1-t^k)}{1-t}
\\&=
\frac1{2k\cdot 2^n}\cdot (2^n-2) \cdot \frac{t(1-t^k)}{1-t}
\\&\leqslant
\frac1{2k} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{t(1-t^k)}{1-t}}_{\beta}.
\end{align}

As $k\to\infty$, $\beta$ approaches $t/(1-t)$ and in particular remains bounded.
It follows from the squeeze theorem that $\alpha$ indeed approaches $0$ as $k\to\infty$, and hence $\pi_n = 2^{-n}$.

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Any vector has the same proportion in the long run. So it has to be $2^{-n}$.

Comment: Is there any detail? thanks.

Comment: @LoveGQY Of course, one could actually _calculate_ the proportion directly. Like the first entry in the $2^n$ long normalized eigen-state-vector of the Markov matrix with eigenvalue $1$. But it's clear that the state vector with only $1$'s is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$, so normalizing that gives you the long-run average state, and you get the same answer. This Markov process is periodic (the sum of 1's in your vector switches between even and odd at each step), so it's not _completely_ cut-and-dry. But it's good enough.

Comment: Ah, they have a point regarding odd/even times, so it is same proportion, but only for same parity.